# How to add a counter in a recursive function in python

Tags: python, recursion

The counter `x` stays 1 throughout the recursion instead of increment.

**My Code**

```
def square(l):
    if len(l) > 0:
        x=0
        print("square of element ", x+1 , ": ", l[0] ** 2)
        square(l[1:])


b = (-2,3,11)
square(b)
```

**Output**

> square of element  1 :  4
>
> square of element  1 :  9
>
> square of element  1 :  121

Is there a way to solve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function to this:

```
def square(l, x=0):
   if len(l) > 0:
       print("square of element ", x+1 , ": ", l[0] ** 2)
       x= x+1
       square(l[1:], x)
```

then:

```
b = (-2,3,11)
square(b)
```

the result will be:

```
square of element  1 :  4
square of element  2 :  9
square of element  3 :  121
```

Answer (score 1):

`x=0` in your code defines a local variable; i.e. a new variable for each instance of the function, when calling square recursively the nested called function will create its own `x`.

A solution is to use a global:

```
x = 0

def square(l):
    if len(l) > 0:
        global x
        x = x+1
        print("square of element ", x , ": ", l[0] ** 2)
        square(l[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Every Time you call your function x is set to zero by this line `x=0` under `if`. You need to change your code. You can follow the following process:

```
x = 0
def square(l):
    global x
    if len(l) > 0:
        x += 1
        print("square of element ", x, ": ", l[0] ** 2)
        square(l[1:])
b = (-2, 3, 11)
square(b)
```

> square of element  1 :  4
>
> square of element  2 :  9
>
> square of element 3 :  121